# How to use select case and alias to sum output

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to create a total miles figure using a select case and alias field.

I have the query below that currently works and will output a total_miles figure.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(s.activity_steps * d.dist_activity_duration / 2000), 2) AS total_miles 
FROM distance d
JOIN activities a 
ON a.id = d.dist_activity_id
JOIN steps s
ON s.id = a.steps_id
JOIN members AS m   
ON d.member_id = m.id
AND m.id = ?
```

I'm having to introduce a new column (dist_is_duration - int) in the DB structure to indicate if the dist_activity_duration value needs to be converted into miles or has been input as miles.

```
dist_activity_duration       dist_is_duration
50                           1
900                          1
60                           0
450                          1
```

I've updated the original query to use a case to check if the duration needs converting or not.

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN d.dist_is_duration = 1 THEN
ROUND(SUM(s.activity_steps * d.dist_activity_duration / 2000), 2)
WHEN d.dist_is_duration = 0 THEN
ROUND(SUM(d.dist_activity_duration), 2)
END AS total_miles
FROM distance d
JOIN activities a 
ON a.id = d.dist_activity_id
JOIN steps s
ON s.id = a.steps_id
JOIN members AS m   
ON d.member_id = m.id
AND m.id = 1
GROUP BY d.dist_is_duration
```

This outputs two values

```
total_miles
25.00
2154.37
```

What I'm aiming for is to get total_miles as a total figure.

Comment: Not only is the logic rather inscrutable, but your first query would return only one row in the result set.  Very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case iif (as proposed by @Van-Macintosh) is not supported by your database :

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(d.dist_activity_duration 
                 * CASE 
                     WHEN d.dist_is_duration = 1 THEN s.activity_steps / 2000 
                     WHEN d.dist_is_duration = 0 THEN 1 
                   END)
                  ,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work for you?

```
sum(iif(d.dist_is_duration = 1, (s.activity_steps * d.dist_activity_duration) / 2000,d.dist_activity_duration)
```

Also you'll need to get rid of the group by if you want one single number.